# printing selected portions of selected rows using awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Assume I have a file called 'file.csv' that contains the following data

```
A:qwe
B:ert
C:rty
```

How would I be able to print out everything before the ':' in rows 2 and 3.
So I want my output to be just B and C. 
Have tried

```
cat file.csv | awk -F ':' '{print $1}'
```

but that prints out A as well and not too sure how to implement 'NR==2,NR==3' to this

Comment: `awk -F: 'NR != 1{print $1}'` if you need to just skip first line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a range of lines from n to m, you can use `sed|cut` combination

```
sed -n '2,3p' file | cut -d: -f1
```

or just `awk`

```
awk -F: 'NR>=2 && NR<=3 {print $1}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Awk seems like ridiculous overkill here. How about this:

```
tail -n 2 | cut -d ":" -f 1
```

Answer (score 0):

`sed` is easier than `awk` for this

```
sed -n '2,3s/:.*//p' file.csv
```

But I'm wondering if you really meant that you want the second and third lines, as opposed to some other criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Perl solution:

```
perl -F: -lane 'print $F[0] if $. > 1' file
```

Prints first field of input if $. (line number variable) > 1

These command-line options are used:

- `n` loop around every line of the input file, do not automatically print every line
- `l` removes newlines before processing, and adds them back in afterwards
- `a` autosplit mode – perl will automatically split input lines into the @F array.  Defaults to splitting on whitespace
- `F` autosplit modifier, in this example splits on ':'
- `e` execute the perl code

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
$ echo "$tgt"
A:qwe
B:ert
C:rty
```

You can use Perl and the 'flip-flop' operator to print the file or text between two line numbers:

```
$ echo "$tgt" | perl -lne 'print $1 if /(^[^:]+)/ and 2..3'
B
C
```

Which works for a file also (obviously)